# How do you convert parameters from char to int in the main function for C?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have this code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int num = *argv[1];
```

When I run the function in terminal with a parameter: for example, if I were to call `./main 17`, I want `num = 17`. However, with this code, `num = 49` (ASCII value for 1 because `argv` is an array of characters). How would I get it to read `num = 17` as an int? Playing around with the code, I can get it to convert the parameter into an int, but it will still only read/convert the first value (1 instead of 17).

I'm new to C and the concept of pointers/pointers to arrays is still confusing to me. Shouldn't `*argv[1]` return the value of the second char in the array? Why does it read the first value of the second char in the array instead?

Thanks for help!

Comment: `argv[1]` is a pointer to `char` holding the 1st whole argument.

Comment: `if (argc > 1) { int num = atoi(argv[1]); }`

Comment: The arguments are strings. You need to convert them to numbers, perhaps with `atoi()` or one of its relatives, or perhaps with `strtol()` or one of its relatives. The latter requires considerable care to get any benefits from it.

Comment: @FilipKočica [Why not to use atoi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17710018/why-shouldnt-i-use-atoi)

Comment: For information on the 'considerable care' required to manage `strtol()`, see [Correct usage of `strtol()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14176123/correct-usage-of-strtol).

Answer (score 2):

> Shouldn't ***argv[1]** return the value of the second char in the array?

Look at the signature:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
```

Here, `argv` is an *array* (`[]`) of *pointers* (`*`) to `char`. So `argv[1]` is the second *pointer* in this array. It points to the *first* argument given at the command line. `argv[0]` is reserved for the name of the program itself. Although this can also be any string, the name of the program is put there *by convention* (shells do this).

If you just dereference a pointer, you get the value it points to, so `*argv[1]` will give you the first character of the first argument. You could write it as `argv[1][0]`, they're equivalent. To get the *second* character of the first argument, you'd write `argv[1][1]`.

---

An important thing to note here is that you **can never pass an array** to a function in C. The signature above shows an array type, but C automatically adjusts array types to pointer types in function declarations. This results in the following declaration:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
```

The indexing operator (`[]`) in C works in terms of pointer arithmetics: `a[x]` is equivalent to `*(a+x)`. The identifier of an array is evaluated as a pointer to the first array element *in most contexts* (exceptions include the `sizeof` operator). Therefore indexing works the same, no matter whether `a` is an array or a pointer. That's why you can treat `argv` very similar to an array.

---

Addressing your "core" problem: You will always have *strings* in `argv` and you want numeric input, this means you have to convert a string to a number. There are already functions doing this. A very simple one is `atoi()`, you can use it like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        // use program name in argv[0] for error message:
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s [number]\n", argv[0]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    int i = atoi(argv[1]);
    printf("Argument is %d.\n", i);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

This will give you `0` if the argument couldn't be parsed as a number and some indeterminate value if it *overflows* your `int`. In cases where you have to make sure the argument **is** a valid integer, you could use `strtol()` instead (note it converts to `long`, not `int`, and it can handle different bases, so we have to pass `10` for decimal):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        // use program name in argv[0] for error message:
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s [number]\n", argv[0]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    errno = 0;    // reset error number
    char *endptr; // this will point to the first character not read by strtol
    long i = strtol(argv[1], &endptr, 10);
    if (errno == ERANGE)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "This number is too small or too large.\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    else if (endptr == argv[1])
    {
        // no character was converted. This also catches the case of an empty argument
        fprintf(stderr, "The argument was not a number.\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    else if (*endptr)
    {
        // endptr doesn't point to NUL, so there were characters not converted
        fprintf(stderr, "Unexpected characters in number.\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    printf("You entered %ld.\n", i);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I'm new to C and the concept of pointers/pointers to arrays is still confusing to me.

In C strings are represented by null terminated (`'\0'`) character arrays. Let's consider the following example:

```
char str[] = "Hello world!"
```

The characters would lie contiguous in memory and the usage of `str` would [decay](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1461449/8051589) to a character pointer (`char*`) that points to the first element of the string. The address of (`&`) the first element taken by `&str[0]` would also point to that address:

```
| . | . | . | H | e | l | l | o |   | W | o | r | l | d | ! | \0 | . | . | . |
              ^                                               ^
             str                                        null terminator
```

> Shouldn't `*argv[1]` return the value of the second char in the array?

First of all in the `argv` is an array of character pointer `char* argv[]`, so that it could be interpreted like an array of strings.

The first string `argv[0]` is the program name of the program itself and after that the arguments that are passed are coming:

```
argv[0] contains a pointer to the string:    "program name"
argv[1] contains a pointer to the argument:  "17"
```

If you dereference `argv[1]` with the use of `*` you get the first character at that address, here `1` which is 49 decimal in the Ascii code. Example:

```
    p             r        ("program name")
    ^             ^
 argv[0]    (argv[0] + 1)
--------------------------------------------
    1             7        ("17")
    ^             ^
 argv[1]    (argv[1] + 1)
```

---

> How would I get it to read `num = 17` as an `int`?

Check the number of passed arguments with `argc` which contains also the program name as one ([read here more about `argc` and `argv`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3024202/8051589)). If there are 2 you can use [`strtol()` to convert](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strtol) `argv[1]` to the an integer. Use `strtol()` over `atoi()` because `atoi()` is considered to be deprecated because there is no error checking available. If `atoi()` fails it simply returns 0 as integer instead of `strtol()` that is setting the second argument and the global `errno` variable to a specific value.

The followig code will use the pointer that `strtol()` set the second argument to, to check for conversion errors. There are also overflow and underflow errors to check [like it's described here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26083517/8051589). Moreover you have to check if the returned `long` value would fit into an `int` variable if you want to store it into an `int` variable. But for simplicity I've left that out:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
   /* At least 1 argument passed? */
   if (argc >= 2)
   {
      char* endptr;
      long num = strtol(argv[1], &endptr, 10);

      /* Were characters consumed? */
      if (argv[1] != endptr)
      {
         printf("Entered number: %ld\n", num);
      }
      else
      {
         printf("Entered argument was not a number!\n");
      }
   }
   else
   {
      printf("Usage: %s [number]!\n", argv[0]);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi @Amy if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 1):

> How do you convert parameters from char to int?

Can be done by a simple cast (promotion), but this isn't your case.

In your case `*argv[]` is *array of pointer to char* (You can use [this](https://cdecl.org/) for breaking down complex C declarations), meaning that `argv[1]` is the 2nd element in the array, i.e. the 2nd `char*` in the array, meaning `*argv[1]` is the first `char` in the 2nd `char*` in the array.

To show it more clearly, assume `argv` holds 2 string `{"good", "day"}`. `argv[1]` is `"day"` and `*argv[1]` is `'d'` (note the difference in types - `char` vs `char*`!)

Now, you are left with the 1st `char` in your input string i.e. `'1'`. Its ascii is indeed 49 as, so in order to get it's `"int"` value you should use `atoi` like this:

```
int i = atoi("17");
```

**BUT** `atoi` gets `const char *` so providing it with `17` is a good idea while sending it a `char` would not. This means `atoi` should get `argv[1]` instead of `*argv[1]`

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
     int num = atoi(argv[1]);
     // not    : int num = *argv[1];        -->  simple promotion that would take the ascii value of '1' :(
     // and not: int num = atoi(*argv[1]);  -->  argument is char
```

*note: `atoi` is considered obsolete so you may want to use `long int strtol(const char *str, char **endptr, int base)` but for a simple example I preferred using `atoi`*

Answer (score -1):

Here's what you want to do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv []) {
    int num = atoi (argv[1]);
    printf ("Here's what you gave me: %d", num);
    return 0;
}
```

Here's the [documentation for atoi ()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/atoi).

`argv` is an array of strings, so argv[x] points to a string. `atoi ()` accepts an ASCII string as input and returns an `int`.

Bonus: This is still a bit unsafe. Try running this program without passing it a parameter and see what happens.

Also, you must take a look at the [documentation for strtol ()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/atoi), which is a safe way of doing this.

Comment: You wont get any argument -> `atoi (argv[1]);` -> UB

Comment: What do you mean @FilipKočica? This works just fine. It lacks a check to see if `argv[1]` points to an actual location, though, which means that it segfaults if you invoke the program with no command line parameters.

Comment: No, it doesn't mean it segfaults. Anything can happen, including but **not limited to** segfault. If `argc` is 0 - yes, this too is allowed, then `argv[1]` need not even be a null pointer.

Comment: That's all true, which is why I added the last edit.