# Trying to get time from command line and store it in struct timespec variable

Tags: c, gcc, time, timespec

I am trying to input a time in a epoch format from the command line and I want to store it in a struct timespec variable.

I am able to store it and somehow print it but when I add something to the timespec variable it is giving strange things

This is the code

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>



int main (int argc, char *argv[]){

    struct timespec InputTime;

    InputTime.tv_sec = (time_t)argv[1]; //(__time_t)
    InputTime.tv_nsec = (long)argv[2]; //(__syscall_slong_t)

    printf("The time before %s,%s\n",
            InputTime.tv_sec,
            InputTime.tv_nsec);

    InputTime.tv_sec += 3;
    InputTime.tv_nsec += 3;

    printf("The time after %s,%s\n",
            InputTime.tv_sec,
            InputTime.tv_nsec);

    return 0;

}
```

This are the inputs and the outputs

```
INPUT

./InputTime 1615578864 438734073

OUTPUT


The time before 140733952311809,140733952311820
The time after 140733952311812,140733952311823
```

I have tried to use other variable types for *argv[] and try to use %s for the output of print but then the time before gives me the right input but the time after gives me something strange here is the example of output when I change %ld to %s. Additionally when i do this the compiler gives some warnings because I am not using the right format

```
./InputTime 1615578864 438734073
The time before 1615578864,438734073
The time after 5578864,734073
```

I am using this gcc version

```
gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Comment: All arguments are *ASCII characters*. If you provide `./your_prog 123` you have provided the ASCII characters `'1'` and `'2'` and `'3'` to your program. You must convert the string to a numeric value with, e.g. `strtol()` before you can use it. (additionally, you should validate the conversion before you use the value as well) See answer to [Detecting strtol failure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26083517/3422102)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuing from my comment above. Any time you read text input in C (as opposed to binary input from a file), you are reading *characters* not numeric values. When the user enters a number, it is a string of digits, not a numeric value. It is up to you, the programmer, to perform the conversion from the string of digits to the numeric value using either the `strtol()` family of functions which provides full error detection, or at minimum, use `sscanf()` to validate the conversion from a succeed/fail standpoint.

In your case, you can simply use `strtoul()` to provide the greatest range for input values. You simply convert `argv[1]` and `argv[2]` to numeric values using `strtoul()`. A minimum validation would be, e.g.

```
    errno = 0;  /* set errno zero before conversion */
    InputTime.tv_sec = strtoul (argv[1], &endptr, 0);   /* convert w/strtoul */
    if (endptr == argv[1] && InputTime.tv_sec == 0) {   /* validate digits converted */
        fputs ("error: no digits converted.\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }
    else if (errno) {   /* validate no overflow in conversion */
        fputs ("error: overflow in conversion.\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }
```

After passing both validations (that digits were converted and that no error occurred during the conversion), you can have confidence that your `struct timespec` contains valid input (you can also further check that the converted numbers are within an acceptable range before use)

If you put it altogether, you can do something like the following:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {

    struct timespec InputTime;
    char *endptr;
    
    if (argc < 3) {
        fputs ("error: insufficient arguments\n"
            "usage: ./progrm seconds nanoseconds\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }
    
    errno = 0;  /* set errno zero before conversion */
    InputTime.tv_sec = strtoul (argv[1], &endptr, 0);   /* convert w/strtoul */
    if (endptr == argv[1] && InputTime.tv_sec == 0) {   /* validate digits converted */
        fputs ("error: no digits converted.\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }
    else if (errno) {   /* validate no overflow in conversion */
        fputs ("error: overflow in conversion.\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }
    
    errno = 0;  /* set errno zero before conversion */
    InputTime.tv_nsec = strtoul (argv[2], &endptr, 0);   /* convert w/strtoul */
    if (endptr == argv[2] && InputTime.tv_nsec == 0) {   /* validate digits converted */
        fputs ("error: no digits converted.\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }
    else if (errno) {   /* validate no overflow in conversion */
        fputs ("error: overflow in conversion.\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }

    printf ("The time before %lu,%09lu\n", InputTime.tv_sec, InputTime.tv_nsec);

    InputTime.tv_sec += 3;
    InputTime.tv_nsec += 3;

    printf ("The time after  %lu,%09lu\n", InputTime.tv_sec, InputTime.tv_nsec);
}
```

(**note:** the inclusion of the `errno.h` header)

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/inputtime_strtol 1615578864 438734073
The time before 1615578864,438734073
The time after  1615578867,438734076
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Perfect  @David C Rankin. It work perfectly thank you very much for the help and the very detailed explanation.